# ActionBar textColor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm trying to change the textColor from my ActionBar doing this :

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(
                    Html.fromHtml("<font color='fff'>"
                            + mDrawerTitle + "</font>"));

            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```

and :

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(
                    Html.fromHtml("<font color='fff'>"
                            + mTitle + "</font>"));

            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
```

But it doesn't work, I've found that you can modify the style.xml but I don't have anything there, I mean, I only have `AppBaseTheme` and `AppTheme`.

Is there any advice that you give you to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a `SpannableString` in this manner:

```
    String text = "Your text";
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
    spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")), 0, text.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    getActionBar().setTitle(spannableString);
```

Or set the attribute `android:textColor` in the **styles.xml** file for your action bar.

Comment: The thing is that I'm changing the title of my ActionBar each time as the user change the option on my drawable navigator.

Comment: Yes, the first approach befits you in that case. You could also use SpannableStringBuilder instead and resetting it every time to bypass String duplication.